# Parsing json object sent with Ajax GET method in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, json

I have created an Ajax request which should be processed by Django:

```
var tracks = [{'artist':'xxx', 'track':'yyy', 'duration':100},
              {'artist':'xxx', 'track':'yyy', 'duration':100},
              {'artist':'xxx', 'track':'yyy', 'duration':100}];
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: ROOT_URL + '/snv/',
  data: {tracks: tracks},
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
  // do something
}).fail(function (data) {
  // do something else
});
```

and I have a Python function to retrieve that data:

```
def snv(request):
    for track in request.GET:
        print track
```

But this function prints something like:

```
tracks[1][artist]
tracks[0][track]
tracks[0][duration]
tracks[2][artist]
tracks[1][track]
tracks[1][duration]
tracks[2][duration]
tracks[0][artist]
tracks[2][track]
```

If I print `request.GET` I get this:

```
<QueryDict: {u'tracks[1][artist]': [u'Artist 02'], u'tracks[0][track]': [u'title 00'], u'tracks[0][duration]': [u'202'], u'tracks[2][artist]': [u'Artist 04'], u'tracks[1][track]': [u'title 02'], u'tracks[1][duration]': [u'506'], u'tracks[2][duration]': [u'233'], u'tracks[0][artist]': [u'Artist 00'], u'tracks[2][track]': [u'title 04']}>
```

How to process my object properly?

Comment: What kind of output do you want?

Comment: I'd like to iterate through the array sent with ajax and insert each object from array into database.

Comment: Can you please show what printing `request.GET` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it like this:

changed my Ajax request from GET to POST,
followed [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) to acquire CSRF_token,
used [this](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser) parser to parse my object,
and finally changed my Python function:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def startNewVoting(request):
  from querystring_parser import parser
  p = parser.parse(request.POST.urlencode())
  for key, track in p['tracks'].iteritems():
    print track
    # save to db...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can solve it by using json encoding:

encode in javascript

```
data: {tracks: JSON.stringify(tracks)}
```

decode in the view

```
tracks = json.loads(request.POST.get('tracks'))
```

This way you avoid 3rd party parser :)

Comment: Thanks! This works for me, including PUT method and complex array item