# Parsing JSON object sent through AJAX in Django

Tags: json, ajax, django, django-views

This is my code creating a json file:

```
$( ".save" ).on("click", function(){
var items=[];


$("tr.data").each(function() {

 var item = {
  itemCode : $(this).find('td:nth-child(1) span').html(),
  itemQuantity : $(this).find('td:nth-child(4) span').html()        
 };
items.push(item);       
 });
});
```

Now the json object looks like:

```
[{"itemcode":"code1","itemquantity":"quantity1"},{"itemcode":"code2","itemquantity":"quantity2"},...]
```

My question is how do I parse this data in Django view?

Following is my AJAX function for reference:

```
(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "", 
        type: "POST",
        data:{ bill_details: JSON.stringify(items),
                calltype:'save'},
        dataType: "application/json", // datatype being sent

        success : function(jsondata) {  

            //do something
        },

            error : function() {
                //do something
            }
    });
}());
```

Since I'm sending multiple AJAX request to the same view, I need the 'calltype' data as well.

Thanks you on your answer!! BTW, I badly need to know this simple stuff, which I'm missing

This is my code snippet for parsing:

```
if (calltype == 'save'):
        response_data = {}
        bill_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('bill_details'))
        itemcode1=bill_details[0]['itemCode'] 
        #this part is just for checking
        response_data['name'] = itemcode1
        jsondata = json.dumps(response_data)
        return HttpResponse(jsondata)
```

The error being raised is

```
string indices must be integers
```

Request your help

For your reference, this is my POST response (taken from traceback):

```
bill_details = '[{"itemCode":"sav","itemQuantity":"4"}]'
calltype = 'save'
csrfmiddlewaretoken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

**EDITED Django View**

This is my edited view:

```
        if (calltype == 'save'):
        bill_detail = request.POST.get('bill_details')
        response_data = {}
        bill_data = json.loads(bill_detail)
        itemcode1=bill_data[0]['itemCode'] 
        #this part is just for checking
        response_data['name'] = itemcode1
        jsondata = json.dumps(response_data)
        return HttpResponse(jsondata)
```

I fail to understand the problem. SO, to solve it, my question: what is the datatype of the return for get call and what should be the input datatype for json.loads. Bcoz the error being shown is json.loads file has to be string type!! (Seriously in limbo)
Error:

```
the JSON object must be str, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Which are the others call types? You should separate the views, create view does only create, update only update and so on. Using CBVs and view inheritance this can be achieved in a very DRY manner. Having different urls for each call type, you won't need to send the calltype param in the json request (and also avoid hard coded values like "save" which is declared on js level and on view level --> headache to maintain.), just change the url where the data is POSTed.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344468/parsing-json-object-sent-with-ajax-get-method-in-django?rq=1

Comment: Hey jabez, thank you.  I'm in the process of learning CBVs - maybe any tips on the best resource would surely help. But as of now could I get a solution to the doubt.

Comment: Guys, this is not a duplicate, as the eroor being raised in nit getting solved by other answers. BTW, I've lready used json.loads() function of python

Comment: I've ran your code and worked fine for me, ofc after I corrected the spelling bill_details/bill_data, itemCode/itemcode and so on. From what I see in your traceback, bill_details is not a list, but a string.

Comment: Hi Jabez, Thanks a lot!! Lmme try with all the spelling n typo issues. BTW, I'm getting to learn CBVs nd ny guess on y my bill_details is not a list but a string?

Comment: in the traceback you posted, the bill_details variable looks to be a string. Good luck with CBVs.

Comment: Hey jabez!! Thanks a lot mate!!Sorry for the late thanks as I was travelling:)  This stupid thing was killing me!!! Finally its working great

Comment: Jabez, if you dont mind,  I have awuestion regarding multi tenancy, might I ask you??